# Detecting ALL open pages in Google Chrome, not just those in the current window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a method similar to:

```
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(integer windowId, function callback)
```

that can get all tabs/pages that are open by the web-browser, whether or not they are in the currently opened window.

I've found:

```
chrome.windows.getAll(object getInfo, function callback)
```

but this by itself does not do what I want.

Can the two be combined somehow to get all the pages currently open in the web browser? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `populate` flag to `getAll` it will return not only all windows but tabs in those windows as well:

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate: true}, function(windows) {
    //each window will contain an array of tabs in it
}
```